# Why isn't console.writeline working in Visual Studio for Mac?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-mac

I've got a console application that I just made in Visual Studio for Mac and in the Program.cs the code that was created automatically apparently had errors. Here is the code:

```
using System;

namespace Console
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        }
    }
}
```

And because it put it there not me, you would expect it to work, but it doesn't, it comes up with this error:

> Console/Program.cs(13,13): Error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'WriteLine' does not exist in the namespace 'Console' (are you missing an assembly reference?) (CS0234) (Console)

How do fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Aren't you overlap namspace `Console` with System's one?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As your namespace is called *Console*, when you call WriteLine, it is trying to find a class within your namespace and overriding the default System.Console.

Either rename you namespace OR explicitly specify the namespace for Console which is in the System namespace:

```
 System.Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
```

Comment: Another alternative is to use `using static System.Console;`. Then you can simply write `WriteLine("Hello World!");`

Comment: Just figured this out right before I read the answer

Comment: Another option would be to put your `using` statements at the deepest scope (ie, within your namespace declaration).  This would also help avoid other naming conflicts.  Eg `namespace Console { using System; class Main {} }`.

Comment: Reverting @GlynnHurrell's recent edit since it was wrong. The original answer was correct. It wasn't looking for a _method_ called `WriteLine` it was looking for a type (just as the error says).